# importing specific information of a text file into a matrix

Tags: matlab, text, matrix

I do appreciate your helps! Thanks in advance!
I have a huge text file in the following format:

```
*********************************
timestep           455
No_Specs             3
H2                  49
H2O2                 1
O2                  49
*********************************
timestep           460
No_Specs             3
H2O                 49
H2O2                 1
O2                  49
*********************************
timestep           465
No_Specs             2
H2                  50
O2                  50
*********************************
```

As you can see the text file includes a lot of loops, each consisting of 4-10 lines ( THE NUMBER OF LINES IS NOT CONSTANT FOR EACH LOOP]. What I want is simply report the number written in front of timestep to the first column of a matrix. Also, I need to find 'H2O ' [ To avoid confusion the extra space is needed ] for any of the loops and report the number in front of it in the second column of that matrix! Obviously if there is not any 'H2O ' in a loop the associated number to that that row is zero!

Here is the code:

```
fid=fopen('fic.txt');
l=fgetl(fid);
k=1;

while ischar(l)        
    r{k}=l;
    k=k+1;
    l=fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
idx=find(~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(r,'(?=timestep).+')));
a=regexp(r(idx),'\d+','match');
b=str2double([a{:}]);
ii=diff([idx numel(r)+1])-1;

for k=1:numel(b);        
    s=r(idx(k)+1:ii(k));
    jj=find(~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(s,'(?=H2O ).+')));
    c=regexp(s(jj),'\d+','match');

    if isempty(c)
        f(k)=0;
    else
        f(k)=str2double(c{1});
    end
end

M=[b' f']
```

Problem with the code is , the elements of the second column are all zero !!! I hope you might be able to help me! I appreciate your helps! Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, there were some indexing errors

```
%%
fid=fopen('fic.txt');
l=fgetl(fid);
k=1;

while ischar(l)        
    r{k}=l;
    k=k+1;
    l=fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
idx=find(~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(r,'(?=timestep).+')));
a=regexp(r(idx),'\d+','match');
b=str2double([a{:}]);
ii=diff([idx numel(r)+1])-1;

for k=1:numel(b);        
    s=r(idx(k)+1:idx(k)+ii(k));
    jj=find(~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(s,'(?=H2O ).+')));
    c=regexp(s(jj),'\d+','match');

    if isempty(c)
        f(k)=0;
    else
        f(k)=str2double(c{1}(2));
    end
end

M=[b' f']
```